# How is the F-test superior to the $\chi^2$-test for handling overdispersion?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm, f-test, overdispersion

I am interested in analyzing data from group randomized trials: a group randomized trial involves recruiting groups, like children within a school, people within a community dwelling, bats in a cave, or teeth in a mouth. The outcomes that are measured are measured within individuals. The group is randomized and exposed to the treatment or control. The outcomes are measured in the individual. Each individual is more correlated within the group than between the group, and yet have varying individual level contributors toward the outcome. The challenge is choosing a regression modeling approach that aggregates conditional individual differences within groups and infers differences in groups and any possible effect of the randomized treatment.

I was reading an article [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25899170) that references a text by Vonesh, SAS inst, saying:

> In the GLMM, the approximated Wald F test, rather than Chi-squared
>   test, is recommended to handle finite sample sizes and overdispersion,
>   which commonly occurs for binary or Poisson regression models, since
>   the variance of both distributions is a function of the mean [8]

The F distribution with $p/n$ degrees of freedom is approximately equal to the $\chi^2$ distribution with $p$ degrees of freedom if $n$ is very large. I presume this statement is made with the expectation that $n$ may not be very large.

Why is it specifically that the degrees of freedom correction "handles...overdispersion"?

Comment: (previous comment replaced) Sorry, I think I follow the question now; I just needed to get a little more of the context. It may be that an introductory sentence or two might make it more clear.